# python pip: "error: legacy-install-failure"

Tags: python, pip, gensim

I want to install `gensim` python package via `pip install gensim`

But this error occurs and I have no idea what should I do to solve it.

```
      running build_ext
      building 'gensim.models.word2vec_inner' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> gensim

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/* do as the tip says.

Comment: @LeiYang I did that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you fail to install plugins,
you can download it from other repositories like this one:
[repository](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gensim) depends on the version of python and the system.

for example: for  windows 11(x64) and python 3.10 you should take this file: ***gensim‑4.1.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl***

Answer (score 3):

i had a similar issue with installing surprise.
Please download build tools from here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Then install some things from here, just tick the box like here

[image]