# pyodbc legacy-install-failure in ubuntu python 3.9

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am not being able to install `pyodbc`

Sorry for the image, but it is on a private network and it does not allow me to do a copy-paste

[image]

[image]

I saw solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295840/python-pip-error-legacy-install-failure), but it is for windows. I can't downgrade my python 3.9 either. Do you know a solution for this `pyodbc` installing?

Comment: If Python.h is missing then you need to `sudo apt install python3-dev`

Comment: Unfortunately it's already installed. Tried that also...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have looked more closely. `python3-dev` installs the headers for Python 3.8.2. Try `sudo apt install python3.9-dev`

Comment: Woow nice! It woked!!! Really thank you Gord! I was spending a lot of time searching for this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue on Python 3.9. Running the following command solved it for me:

```
sudo apt install unixodbc-dev
```