# How to resolve error, "legacy-install-failure" when installing package pysha3 in PyCharm using python 3.11 on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pip, pycharm

I'm pretty new to programming in python, and the reason why I am using or have been learning python as of now is to complete an assignment. However, when downloading a source code and attempting to use it, I encountered errors that I cannot resolve. The source code is from this website "https://github.com/ZeroProphet/klefki#readme. If anyone can help me with this problem, that would be great.

I tried updating the pip version and even doing a specific step-by-step installation of the package in PyCharm. I expect it to be downloaded successfully, but it keeps stating that it cannot build the wheel for pysha3 and legacy-install-failure. If anything, try running this program and see if you're experiencing similar issues.

This error is shown when I attempt to run the program:

````
Collecting pyasn1==0.3.7
  Using cached pyasn1-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting base58==0.2.5
  Using cached base58-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
Collecting asn1ate==0.6.0
  Using cached asn1ate-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pysha3==1.0.2
  Using cached pysha3-1.0.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting flatbuffers==1.12
  Using cached flatbuffers-1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.0
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pysha3
  Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pysha3 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pysha3
Failed to build pysha3
Installing collected packages: pysha3, pyasn1, flatbuffers, base58, pyparsing, asn1ate
  Running setup.py install for pysha3: started
  Running setup.py install for pysha3: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [9 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  copying sha3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  running build_ext
  building '_pysha3' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysha3
  **error: subprocess-exited-with-error**
  
  Running setup.py install for pysha3 did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [11 lines of output]
  running install
  C:\Users\sxmfc\Downloads\klefki-master\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  copying sha3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
  running build_ext
  building '_pysha3' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
**error: legacy-install-failure**

Encountered error while trying to install package.

pysha3

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pip: "error: legacy-install-failure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295840/python-pip-error-legacy-install-failure)

Comment: No, that does not. Have you tried running this program? I am an inexperienced GitHub user and a python programmer, so it would be nice to get some help from experts in this matter :)

Comment: No, I havent, but from further inspection, [pysha3 is no longer supported](https://github.com/tiran/pysha3) and has been implemented to python 3.6. So probably you have to raise an issue to klefki's creator.